# Accessing object from different class Python

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to python, and I'm using PyCharm. I met a problem when trying to access a list in an object.

I have a file to store the list object, let's say Box.py, and a main file to run the programme, Main.py.

And this is what is inside my Box.py:

```
class Container:
    def __int__(self):
        self.list = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

And now I want to print the `list` in the class `Container` from my Main.py.

This is what I wrote for my Main.py:

```
from MainProgramme import Container

def main():
    container = Box.Container()
    print(container.list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So, I have created an object `container`, and use it to access the list in the object.

But when I run the Main.py, there was an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm\MyProject\MainProgramme\Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\PyCharm\MyProject\MainProgramme\Main.py", line 5, in main
    print(container.list)
AttributeError: 'Container' object has no attribute 'list'
```

May I know what is the problem, and how do I solve it?

Comment: `__int__` should be `__init__`

Comment: also be aware because you are importing `Container` from module, and when creating object you use dot like you want to module access `container = Box.Container()`, it should be `container = Container()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, you aren't actually calling init.

```
def __int__(self):
```

should be

```
def __init__(self):
```

Also, to run your code, I had to change the creation of the Container object.

```
container = Box.Container()
```

Comment: Oh, I missed the comments.. :S I though that this solves the problem.
What should I do? Delete the answer?

Comment: I don't think you'll have to if you didn't see the comment :) refer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304126/is-it-correct-to-answer-copying-from-comments-by-other-users